# Python GUI refreshing at a fixed rate

Tags: python, pyqt, pyopengl

I am pretty confused about this. I need to create a Python-based GUI that should make changes in objects at a fixed rate. Ideally, this rate should be 60 Hz (monitor refresh rate).

Until now, I have a PyQt GUI that displays what I want, controlled by a QThread that monitors the elapsed time and sends PyQtSignals to the Main GUI after 0.016s (60 Hz ideally) to update things. My problem is that the PyQt signal lasts several milliseconds to reach the Main GUI and thus, I cannot reach 60 Hz. Moreover, the frame rate is not constant, but it varies between 50-55ms...

This is terrible for my application. My desired GUI SHOULD be updated at a **fixed** rate. It is preferable to run it at 55Hz without deviation that having non-constant FPS between 50-60.

So I heard about PyGame and PyOpenGL, but the documentation regarding this topic is almost unreadable for me. I would like to know what would be the best approach to follow: PyOpenGL, PyQt, PyGame, Unity? And, of course, I would appreciate it a lot if someone could give me some information regarding this or even a dummy 1-min script to demonstrate the general skeleton to follow.

Comment: Why do you need a fixed frame rate? In video games, FPS will change based on system resources and system load but game play remains the same. For your gui updates, do you need to see every frame or is skipping allowed (for slow systems)?

Comment: PyGame is low level library and you have to write event loop on your own. It may try to run as fast as it possible and yo may use `pygame.clock` to slow down to 60 FPS. But it can't guarantee fixed speed 60 FPS. Many games used loop which doesn't try to keep fixed rate but rather use `dt` ("delta time" - time used to draw previous frame) to calculate object's position in next frame. This way it can works smooth even if FPS changed from 60 to 15 and back to 60. I expect that `Unity` also can't guarantee fixed speedand it uses `dt` to make smooth animation.

Comment: In this case, this GUI is not intended to be part of a videogame. It will be part of a psychological research study. That's why I need a fixed rate :(

Comment: Does your code have a explicit delay (ie. sleep) for 0.016s?

Comment: @Mike67 Yes! I know that the previous lines would consume some ms and thus, the sleep will make the time vary. I corrected it using a variable sleep depending on the time that was consumed by the previous computation, but it keepsdoing the same, so I thought it was provoked by the pyqtsignal delay

Comment: Sounds like you will need to use some sort of timer in your code so the signal always *starts* at the correct moment and the time required for signal process is ignored. This should give you a consistent FPS.

Comment: Do you know how could I implement that? Please take into consideration that the Timer (ej: QTimer) cannot update the gui, so I need to communicate with my GUI main anyway :(

If you could write a very small skeleton i'd accept that as the answer ^^^

Answer (score 0):

The QTimer seems to have only 1ms resolution for event firing. My current solution is using PyQt5 QTimer for approximate timing, and then time.perf_counter() for precision:

```
class Widget1(Qwidget):
  def __init__():
    self.tick_timer = QTimer(self)
    self.tick_timer.singleShot(16, self.tick)
    self.t0 = time.perf_counter()

  def tick(self):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    while (t1 - self.t0) > 0.016666:
      t1 = time.perf_counter()
      QApplication.processEvents()
    self.t0 = t1
    self.tick_timer.singleShot(16, self.tick)
    self.update() # or repaint()

 def paintEvent(self, event):
    ....
```